# whats wrong with this code? not populating table from core data!! iPad

Tags: ipad, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller

Please help me to fix this issue (Im getting crazy now!), My project is saving the data properly to the sqlite db in coredata, as checked in a SQLite grapical manager,but I dont seem to be able to show it in a table view, I need my table inside my viewController (small table not whole screen),

If you feel generous please check my little sample project
[Here Thankyou!](http://www.kadekamstaffs.com.au/coredata/CoreDataEnsaShow5.zip)

here the code of the *viewcontroller.h

(Please note that I included a IBoutlet for the table view as tableView is not an instance in UIViewController!) was this done properly?,
also, I get 7 warnings where i call the tableView> Local declaration of 'tableView' hides instance variable

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CoreDataEnsaViewController : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> //va     controller delegate??


{

UITextField *name;
UITextField *address;
UITextField *phone;
UILabel         *status;


//la table
//NSMutableArray *array;

//la tabla??
UITableView *tableView;
NSFetchedResultsController *_fetchedResultsController;
NSManagedObjectContext *_context;  
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *status;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

- (IBAction) saveData;
- (IBAction) findContact;
- (IBAction) showbtn:(id) sender;

@end
```

and here the *viewController.m

```
#import "CoreDataEnsaViewController.h"
#import "CoreDataEnsaAppDelegate.h"
#import "ShowViewController.h"

#import "Contacts.h"

@implementation CoreDataEnsaViewController

ShowViewController *showView;

@synthesize name, address, phone, status, tableView;

@synthesize context = _context;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

-(IBAction) showbtn:(id) sender {

showView = [[ShowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowViewController"  bundle:nil];

//anima
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
   [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:showView.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];  

}

  - (void) saveData
 {
CoreDataEnsaAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject *newContact;

newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts"  inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newContact setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"];
[newContact setValue:address.text forKey:@"address"];
[newContact setValue:phone.text forKey:@"phone"];

name.text = @"";
address.text = @"";
phone.text = @"";

NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
status.text = @"Contact saved";
    }

    - (void) findContact
   {
CoreDataEnsaAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name = %@)", name.text];

[request setPredicate:pred];

NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
NSError *error;

NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) {
    status.text = @"No matches";
} else {
    matches = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    address.text = [matches valueForKey:@"address"];
    phone.text = [matches valueForKey:@"phone"];
    status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d matches found", [objects  count]];
}
[request release];
    }

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

//NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"details.closeDate"  ascending:NO];
//[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[fetchRequest release];
[theFetchedResultsController release];

return _fetchedResultsController;    


}




// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Overriden to allow any orientation.
return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.name = nil;
self.address = nil;
self.phone = nil;
self.status = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}



//tabla

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController  sections] objectAtIndex:section];
 return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

//return [array count];
//return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
  }


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Contacts *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = info.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", info.address, info.phone];

}


  //---insert individual row into the table view---

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//---try to get a reusable cell---

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



//---create new cell if no reusable cell is available---

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


}


// Set up the cell...
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];



return cell;

 } 



  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];



}

 //tabla end



 - (void)dealloc {
[name release];
[address release];
[phone release];
[status release];

self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
self.context = nil;

[super dealloc];
}


 #pragma mark NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications,  so    prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            // Reloading the section inserts a new row and ensures that titles are updated appropriately.
            [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];}



@end
```

The connections in the xib are>
table view
outlet:
data source-----------files owner;
delegate--------------files owner;
referencing outlets
tableView-------------files owner;
thank you so much!!!!

Comment: ok, code from link updated to my last project, thank you!!

Comment: You project's link seems to be offline...

Comment: link working now, but still stuck with the problem!!, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code to perform a fetch of data in your viewDidLoad method:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unsolved error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Contacts''

Comment: I get the above error if I include the code in the view did load!, thank you, whats wrong aaahh :(

Comment: This error makes me think that there is any problem with your managedObjectContext ... Try to double-check the code and if you have not already done so, try to see the project provided by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

As for the "NSInternalConsistencyException" check the managed object model against your code and make sure you're calling it exactly right. Failing that, have you done a clean, restarted XCode, restarted your computer, deleted app from simulator, the usual stuff? If you've made changes to the file or swapped it out, the old stuff will sometimes "lurk" and cause these issues. Failing that, sometimes when I've had a confounding core data problem, rebuilding the model file from scratch and auto-creating the subclasses over will fix it...don't know why.

I know this wasn't your question, but it's widely discouraged to simply call the app delegate for the managed object context--though it does work and you'll see it in some code examples, it's not best practice. It introduces an unnecessary dependency in your project which will make your code harder to maintain. The app delegate should only be used to handle system-level events as it was designed, not "abused" for other purposes. The better way is to create a managed object context property for each controller that needs it, and pass the reference when that controller is created. Your App Delegate will pass it to the root view controller in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (simply by setting the receiving controller's property), like this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...
{
  UINavigationController *navController = self.window.rootViewController
  MyViewController *controller = navController.viewControllers[0];
  controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

  return YES;
}
```

When that root view controller needs to pass the MOC to another controller, it happens like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue...
{
  MyOtherController *otherController = [segue destinationViewController];
  controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

And so on and so forth, for each controller that needs it. That way you aren't introducing unnecessary dependencies that make your code less modular and reusable.

Hope this helped.